# How to append attribute using variable in Eloquent PHP

Tags: php, eloquent

I am starting with Eloquent and I would like to add a new attribute to a model that depends on a variable.

I have added several custom attributes like this:

```
protected $appends = ['people'];
public function getPeopleAttribute() {
    return $this->users()->where('active', '=', 1)->count();
}
```

But I need to add a new attribute that depends on a variable, something like this:

```
protected $appends = ['people', 'similars'];
public function getSimilarsAttribute() {
    return $this->users()->where('property', '=', $variable)->count();
}
```

How can I pass $variable to getter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This not possible as you are actual going to use `$model->similar` which is something you can't give a variable to.

here is how you could do this (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeSimilars($query, $variable)
{
    return $query->users()->where('property', '=', $variable)->count();
}
```

if you use it you can simply do the `YourModel::similars('fooBar')`

Comment: Hi DouglasDC3,
Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work.
I need to add a new attribute to the model that depends on a variable, a custom select, not a where condition.

If I got the aim of scopes, it adds a condition to the query, but not the attribute value to the select.

Thank you anyway. I didn't know about scopes, and it could be useful in the future